# How to implement codes in GUI formed apps in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I really have a hard time finding help on internet since no one is giving examples on how to implement codes in GUI formed app. So I have my interface created and whole app works through buttons. Every code I find is for just workspace line, or how would I call it. Now I want do the following:
I have an input page for registering members in the gym. When I register them, they go to jTable. Now, I want to make it possible to edit columns *Weight* and *Instructor* from the table. I saw how to add ComboBox into table column, but don't know how do it in GUI formed app, where table is not created by the code. And I want to edit Weight column with jTextField the same I would do with ComboBox for instructors.

**The question can also be: How do I define these custom things in table (or any other *object* in GUI Java App) when I already have GUI table set on place with drag and drop in NetBeans?**

Comment: *How do I define these custom things in table ... when I already have GUI table set on place with drag and drop in NetBeans?* - don't use Netbeans drag and drop. You are spending time learning how to use the IDE instead of Swing. If you ever move to a different IDE  you won't be able to maintain your code. Instead learn how to write code and extend classes on your own to customize the functionality.

Comment: Well hi again. I know what you mean, but the only reason I like Java is that GUI option to make my apps interface and code it. I don't even know where to start from, I have to do everything from the beginning. Our classes were terrible and we only learned how to use NetBeans. Drag components that we need and program them to do what we want. I HAVE NO IDEA how to use classes and objects. I did read the book, tho it's just theory and it's for making libraries for people to use, and it's badly written. So I feel terrible right now because I see how little I know and how useless my knowledge is.

Comment: *I don't even know where to start from,* - start by reading tutorials. Start by playing with working examples and then making changes. You could start with the code example from   the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for lots of basic info on tables. However, the code examples always create a custom TableModel by extending AbstractTableModel. This is not always necessary since the `DefaultTableModel` will work in most situations when you are just learning.

Comment: So I might suggest you could start with the table example from [How to Write a ListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) which will have an example that uses the `DefaultTableModel`. The point is you need to read and experiment.

Comment: Yes, but tell me...if I'm not using IDE where do I code and how do I open a new project without Java Frame. Is it just Java Class then or Java Interface? Where can I find materials from learning it from 0. And what is in your opinion on Swing and should I even bother learning it, or I sould just learn some other Java?

Comment: And, if I code that way, will I still be able to modify and create custom interface for my app?
Sorry if I'm asking too much...

Comment: You can use the IDE to write the code manually and compile and debug. You just don't want the IDE to generate the code. There are plenty of example from the tutorials that you just copy/paste/compile and test.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll do my best.